# Is the Second Partial Derivative equal to the First Partial Derivative Squared?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, derivatives

In most situations, it is obvious that the second partial derivative is NOT equal to the first partial derivative squared.

However, I was reading the following page and noticed the following statement:

[image]

Here, it seems that the (expected value of the) second partial
derivative is in fact equal to the (expected value of the) first partial derivative squared.

To give some context, we are dealing with the Log Likelihood Function of a Probability Distribution Function from the field of Statistics.

I tried to look more into this and couldn't find any more information as to why this relationship is true. Could someone please comment on this - **in this particular case, why is the second partial  derivative equal to squaring the first partial derivatives?**

Thanks!

Comment: They are not first and second derivatives, they are the mixed partial derivative, and the two partial derivatives...

Comment: @ Arturo : Thanks! I made this correction just now!

Comment: Furthermore, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$$Should be read: "dee-*two*-y by dee x-squared" and is certainly *not* equal to $\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^2$ in most cases

Comment: @ Fshrike: Thank you for this comment!

Comment: Partial derivatives with respect to different variables are usually different. We usually don't refer to the multiplication of two different things as "squaring." There is also a sign change from the left to the right side that you wouldn't see if we were dealing with the square of some value.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Since the equation is a special property of the $L_i$ function (and not a property of functions in general), an answer might need to know more exactly what $L_i$ is in that source context.

Comment: @ aschepler: thank you for your reply! L_i are the individual likelihood contributions. I will add this to the original question!

Comment: This is a special case of a known property used in [Fisher Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) derivation. In the link you can find a proof of both versions (read first the " then the Fisher information may also be written as" part - which basically answers your question)

Comment: @ leonbloy: thank you so much! I will take a look at this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been explained by leonbloy's comment, but I will spell it out.  By the definition of $L_i$, we have
$$
L_i(y_i, {\pmb \beta})=\log p(y_i; {\pmb \beta}), \qquad \hbox{where $p(y_i; {\pmb \beta})$ is the probability density of $y_i$ given $\pmb \beta$}
$$
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
-\frac{\partial^2 L_i}{\partial \beta_h \partial \beta_j}
&=& -\frac{\partial^2(\log p) }{\partial \beta_h \partial \beta_j}\\
&=& -\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_h} \left(\frac{1}{p} \frac{\partial p}{\partial \beta_j}\right)\\
&=&
\frac{1}{p^2} \frac{\partial p}{\partial \beta_h}\frac{\partial p}{\partial \beta_j}
-\frac{1}{p}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial \beta_h \partial \beta_j}\\
&=& 
\left( \frac 1 p \frac{\partial p}{\partial \beta_h} \right)
\left( \frac 1 p \frac{\partial p}{\partial \beta_j} \right)
-\frac{1}{p}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial \beta_h \partial \beta_j}\\
&=&
\frac{\partial (\log p)}{\partial \beta_h}
\frac{\partial (\log p)}{\partial \beta_j}
-\frac{1}{p}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial \beta_h \partial \beta_j}\\
&=&
\frac{\partial L_i}{\partial \beta_h}
\frac{\partial L_i}{\partial \beta_j}
-\frac{1}{p}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial \beta_h \partial \beta_j}
\end{eqnarray*}
and taking expected values gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(
-\frac{\partial^2 L_i}{\partial \beta_h \partial \beta_j}
\right)
=
E\left(
\frac{\partial L_i}{\partial \beta_h}
\frac{\partial L_i}{\partial \beta_j}
\right)
-E\left(
\frac{1}{p}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial \beta_h \partial \beta_j}
\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
which is what we want, except that we must get rid of the second term.  But by the definition of the expected value,
$$
E(f)=\int f(y_i, {\pmb \beta})\, p(y_i; {\pmb \beta}) \, dy_i \qquad \hbox{for any function $f$}
$$
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left(
\frac{1}{p}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial \beta_h \partial \beta_j}
\right)
&=&
\int \frac{1}{p}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial \beta_h \partial \beta_j} \, p \, dy_i \\
&=& \int \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial \beta_h \partial \beta_j}
\, dy_i \\
&=& \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \beta_h \partial \beta_j}
\int p \, dy_i \\
&=& \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \beta_h \partial \beta_j} 1,
\qquad \hbox{since $p$ is a probability density}\\
&=& 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you! This was really cool!